# SELECT name d , id r from ano where id != :P11_ANOID

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-apex, where-clause

I have a single page of master region with detail region. On both region I create the page item (SELCT LIST) of P11_ANOID and column in detail table ANOID (select list). Same list are used in bot page item and column but I want to filter the selected return id from P11_ANOID not present in the list of column. I used the query to filter in column list is

```
SELECT name d 
       , id r 
from ano  
where id != :P11_ANOID
```

but this can't work the. in this case the list cannot show for where condition? can anyone please help.?

Comment: can you share sample data?

Comment: If that is a list variable, then you will want to run it through apex_string.split https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/SPLIT-Function-Signature-1.html#GUID-3BE7FF37-E54F-4503-91B8-94F374E243E6 to convert it to a collection (I don’t recall what the separator is), you can then use `not in (select * from table(apex_string.split(...)))`

Comment: both the master item's list and the detail column's list are set from the same table by sql query. but I want to filter the detail column list not having the value selected in master's item list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then `P11_ANOID` Select List item's value isn't "visible" to detail region's LoV query. Read: it isn't in the session state.

What to do? Change "Page action on selection" property for the `P11_ANOID` item to e.g. **Submit** or "Redirect and set value".

Comment: both the master item's list and the detail column's list are set from the same table by sql query. but I want to filter the detail column list not having the value selected in master's item list.

Comment: OK. So, did you do what I suggested?

Comment: kindly will you please explain again i didnt get